# Permission Denied for user on Schema in Postgress

Tags: postgresql

I have created a new schema `dev` within my DB and created a set of views within it that are pulling from the `live` schema. So the view is a `view` of a `live` table.

I have granted myself access using the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA dev TO bob;
```

I checked my access using:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee = 'bob'
```

It shows I have select access to all the views in the schema

The user does not have access to the `live` schema

When I log in and try and access any of the views in `dev` I get a permissions error?

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema dev
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM dev.test
SQL state: 42501
Character: 15
```

It seems to be pointing to the `dev` prefix but if I remove that I then get a relation error even though the default schema is pointing to `dev`.
I've tried removing the user and adding him back but I get the same issue. I've also tried this in Windows and Ubuntu with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to give USAGE ON the schema

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dev TO bob;
```

Comment: thanks! I spent a few days searching online and didn't see this.

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek you are wellcome)